# How to link two values to dropdown in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

I have created entites and facde in netbeans. Now I want to create a native query to get only two feilds from the table. And then Bind them to the

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT(m.idManufacturer),m.hmid "
                + " FROM model m";

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<model> modelList = (List&lt;model>) getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
```

and then I used this code

```
<f:selectItems itemLabel="#{myController.modelList.idManufacturer}"/>
```

to show values in dropdown. But that doesn't seem working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating list of [selectItems](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) from your `List<Model>` and give that in value attribute.

e.g.

```
List<SelectItem> modelList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
  //implement your conversion label value here.
<f:selectItems value="#{myController.modelList}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on JSF 1.x, you need to provide a `SelectItem[]`, `List<SelectItem>` or `Map<String, Object>` to the `value` of  `f:selectItems`. The most common choice is a `List<SelectItem>`. Assuming that you want to use `Model#getIdManfacturer()` (which I assume to be a `Long`) as both item label *and* value, here's an example:

```
public class Bean {
    private Long selectedManfacturerId; // +getter +setter
    private List<SelectItem> selectManfacturerIds; // +getter

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        selectManfacturerIds = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        List<Manfacturer> manfacturers = getItFromDatabaseSomehow();
        for (Manfacturer manfacturer : manfacturers) {
            selectManfacturerIds.add(new SelectItem(manfacturer.getManfacturerId()));
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

in combination with

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedManfacturerId}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectManfacturerIds}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

---

However, if you're already on JSF 2.0, then you can also just use a `List<SomeBean>` for this. The new `var` attribute in a JSF 2.0 `<f:selectItems>` allows you to declare the iterated item in the view. Kickoff example:

```
public class Bean {
    private Long selectedManfacturerId; // +getter +setter
    private List<Manfacturer> manfacturers; // +getter

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        manfacturers = getItFromDatabaseSomehow();
    }

    // ...
}
```

in combination with

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedManfacturerId}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.manfacturers}" var="manfacturer" itemValue="#{manfacturer.manfacturerId}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```